# Need help in connecting my Samsung mobile

Tags: networking

I use [TP-link Archer AC1200] as my primary router (according to my phone, I think my router’s IP address = `192.168.0.1`) with SSID-1. Connected to it is the [TOTOLINK A2004NS] (whose LAN IP = `192.168.31.103`) with SSID-2. It is followed by another router [TP-link WR1042ND IP] (IP address = `192.168.31.8` ******) with SSID-3.

I have three cell phones:

(A) Redmi 6 plus
  (B) LG Stylus 3
  (C) Samsung A6-2018

Both (A) and (B) can access all those SSIDs, but (C) can access SSID-1 and SSID-2 only. It can detect the signal from SSID-3, but reports that there is no internet connection.

Below. The pictures on the right show that All three can be interneted via SSID-1. Those on the left show that Samsung alone canNOT be internet to SSID-3 while the other two can. [The meaning of those Chinese words shown on the Samsung means "internet option may not be available".]

[image]

Are there any other extra settings that I need to fix the Samsung phone?

Additional info:-

This incident happens when I have added the AC1200 as the new primary router. That is, before that I just had the A2004NS and the WR1042ND but all three mobiles worked well.

Comment: Why do SSID-2 and SSID-3 have the same IP addresses?

Comment: @ReddyLutonadio My post was edited (but wrongly). Fixed with additional info.

Comment: If SSID-1 and SSID-2 are off or down, is the phone able to connect to the internet via SSID-3?

Comment: @ReddyLutonadio Since SSID-1 is the primary router and therefore is the main passage to the internet, it must not be down. Tried just shutting down SSID-2 alone, all of the phones were down; including the computer (through  network cable).

Comment: @ReddyLutonadio I have added some pictures to clarify my question.

Comment: I am sorry but the image quality is so bad that I can't see anything of that photos. Use the screenshot function on the affected device to create images and upload them separately. Does the affected device really has no Internet access (sometimes Android is wrong) - ehich IP address does it get? BTW: Your network design is really strange. Why 3 routers? Are they cascaded -if yes why? Which router is the one that has really Internet access? Which one is active as DHCP server?

Comment: @Robert  The facts I want to show are (1) (Pictures on the right) Phones are placed side by side on the same spot & the result is all 3 can be interneted w/o any problem. (2) (Those on the left) The Lan, Lg, & Redmi can be interneted thro the same router (SSID-3) but the Samsung cant. I think the explanation is:- (1) I just have my  broadband changed from 500m to 1000m recently. That router (150 m only) is too old. (2) The checking for a good internet connection by Samsung is too strong & therefore it doesn't let go while the non Samsung's have lesser requirement. Will take away the old.